# Can pytorch compute gradients for composite tensors?

Tags: pytorch, tensor, autograd

Suppose I have a parameter `p` and a big tensor `a` initialized as:

```
a = torch.empty(size=[50] + list(p.shape))
```

I then fill `a` as follows:

```
for i in range(a.shape[0]):
    a[i] = torch.pow(p, i) #more complex computation here.
```

---

**EDIT**

To add clarity, I will make the computation a bit more explicit:

Suppose I have a torch module `net`, I compute `a` as follows:

```
import torch.nn as nn

p = torch.ones(10)
net = nn.Linear(p.shape[0], p.shape[0])

a[0] = p
for i in range(a.shape[0]):
    a[i] = net(a[i-1])
```

---

I then use `a` to compute my loss, for example:

```
loss = a.sum()
loss.backward()
```

Can pytorch compute the gradients through `a` despite the different computation paths for its subtensors?

What about if I were to use `torch.stack` on a list of the tensors obtained in the loop.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see from your example, you could initialize `a` directly without requiring an intermediate tensor to be created or a *for* loop to be used. 
You can leverage [`torch.arange`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.arange.html) to do so:

```
>>> a = p**torch.arange(len(p))
```

Comment: As mentioned in the comment, there is a more complex computation than just the power operation. The power function is just to illustrate.

Comment: @hamzakeurti I believe you should show what kind of operation is performed then.

Comment: I just added an example that maybe better portrays what I am doing. Although not exactly. But just to show why an immediate computation is not possible.